# Anaconda Jupyter Notebook error for !pip install Twisted

Tags: python-3.x, pip, twisted, twisted.internet

I am trying to do a `!pip install Twisted` and I am getting an error "Failed building wheel for Twisted" Any ideas? Is there any methods for installing a .wheel file directly with IPython if I download the .whl file directly from pypi.org??

Comment: Have you tried `conda install twisted`?

Comment: No I havent Ill have to look into that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. And solved it doing:

```
conda install twisted
```

as said by notorious.no